# Can I use setProgress to change a seek bar programatically

Tags: android, android-camera, seekbar, zooming

I am using an android `seekBar` as a camera zoom controller.

The seek bar works like a charm when dragging but I wanted to add a zoomIn and zoomOut button that would increment the progress.  Problem is two fold.

1. When I click the button I have to click it 4 times before the progress actually increments
2. It is not updating the draggable thumb on the progress bar

   ```
   btn_zoomIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
       try {
         zoomCtrl.setProgress(zoomCtrl.getProgress()+1);
         onProgressChanged(zoomCtrl, zoomCtrl.getProgress(), true);
       } catch(Exception ex) { }
     }
   });

   btn_zoomOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
       try {
         zoomCtrl.setProgress(zoomCtrl.getProgress()-1);
       } catch(Exception ex){ }
     }
   });
   ```

Can anyone help please?

**ADDITION:**

this is the verticalSeekBar class i am using instead of seekBar:

```
public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

/**
 * Instantiates a new vertical seek bar.
 *
 * @param context the context
 */
public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {

    super(context);
}

/**
 * Instantiates a new vertical seek bar.
 *
 * @param context the context
 * @param attrs the attrs
 * @param defStyle the def style
 */
public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/**
 * Instantiates a new vertical seek bar.
 *
 * @param context the context
 * @param attrs the attrs
 */
public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.AbsSeekBar#onSizeChanged(int, int, int, int)
 */
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

    super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.AbsSeekBar#onMeasure(int, int)
 */
@Override
protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.AbsSeekBar#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
 */
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {

    c.rotate(-90);
    c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

    super.onDraw(c);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.AbsSeekBar#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
        onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

and i am adding it to my activity like so:

```
zoomCtrl = new VerticalSeekBar(this);
        zoomCtrl.setLayoutParams(zCtrl);

        zoomCtrl.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.zoombar_progress_bg));
        zoomCtrl.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagebtn_zoom_thumb));
        zoomCtrl.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.zoom_track));
        zoomCtrl.setPadding(25, 0, 25, 0);
        zoomCtrl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);


        rel.addView(zoomCtrl);
```

Comment: seekbar.setProgress(seekbar.getProgress()+5)
and seekbar.setOffsetThumb(int offset) or seekbar.setThumb(drawable)

Comment: setThumb()?  its already set.. setThumbOffset()?  how do i determin offset int?

Comment: actually i don't want to reset the offset.. thats not good

Answer (score 10):

Solved the issue by overriding setProgress in VerticalSeekbar class.
`@Override
    public synchronized void setProgress(int progress) { 
        super.setProgress(progress); 
        onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0); 
  }`

Answer (score 3):

Create updateThumb(); method in VerticalSeekbar

```
    public void updateThumb(){
         onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
    }
```

And then call update thumb method after setting progress.

```
seekBar.setProgress(100 - (int) progress);
seekBar.updateThumb();
```